# C# Validation of two TextBoxes on different pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have two pages. The first page is a registration page where the user creates a user name and password. The second page is a log in page, where the user enters their user name and password.  I want to validate that the two match, on the front-end.  I stored the user name and password in a session and am not using a database.  This isn't working and I'm unsure why:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Information> downloadList = (List<Information>)Session["DownloadList"];
        foreach (Information obj1 in downloadList)
        {
            newName = String.Format("{0}", obj1.name);
            newPassword = String.Format("{0}", obj1.email);
        }
            if(newName != TextBoxUserNameMatch.Text)
        {
            LabelLoginError.Text = "You Must Enter the Correct User Name";
        }
            else if(newPassword != TextBoxPasswordMatch.Text)
        {
            LabelLoginError.Text = "You Must Enter the Correct Password";
        }
            else
        {
            Response.Redirect("DownloadPage.aspx");
        }

    }
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong here?  Here is the class information:

```
public class Information
{
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String email { get; set; }
    public String phone { get; set; }
    public String zip { get; set; }
    public String state { get; set; }
    public String login { get; set; }
    public String password { get; set; }
    public String reenter { get; set; }

    public Information(String name, String email, String phone, String zip, String state, String login, String password, String reenter)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.zip = zip;
        this.state = state;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
        this.reenter = reenter;
    }
}
```

Here is the code behind my Registration page:

```
public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            Information download1 = new Information("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");

            Session["Info1"] = download1;

            DropDownListState.Items.Add(download1.name);
        }

    }

    protected void ButtonRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name = TextBoxName.Text;
        String email = TextBoxEmail.Text;
        String phone = TextBoxPhone.Text;
        String zip = TextBoxZip.Text;
        String state = DropDownListState.SelectedItem.Text;
        String login = TextBoxLogIn.Text;
        String password = TextBoxPassword.Text;
        String reenter = TextBoxReenter.Text;

        if(Session["DownloadList"] == null)
        {
            List<Information> downloadList = new List<Information>();
            Session["DownloadList"] = downloadList;
        }
        Information obj1 = new Information(name, email, phone, zip, state, login, password, reenter);

        List<Information> downloadList2 = (List<Information>)Session["DownloadList"];
        downloadList2.Add(obj1);
        Session["DownloadList"] = downloadList2;

        Response.Redirect("Confirmation.aspx");
```

I believe these parts are working correctly because on my final page I have it printing out the user's name and email and that is working correctly.

Comment: No matter what I enter it gives me the first error message

Comment: Why are you looping through `downloadList` if you're only going to compare the last value?

Comment: #Dour High Arch, I don't know how to call the list in a session otherwise.

Comment: Did you debug the code? Are you getting proper values from session? Can you also share the code which stores the value in session?

Comment: #Chetan Ranpariya  Thanks for looking at it and not judging an aspiring programmer.  I edited my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll need to really start from the beginning because as John Wu stated, there's a lot wrong here and this forum isn't the place to get a tutorial. No judgement(s), just fact. Start with understanding what a [`Session` is and it's scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx). The first paragraph of that link should hopefully push you to a different approach.

Comment: First you need to debug the code and check what values you are getting from the session. Second, You don't need list of Information to store information of one user. You can directly store one object of Information class in session.

Comment: The above code doesn't make any sense. In Button1_Click it loops through values in downloadList and overwrites newName and newPassword. Just tell us what you want to do and let's start there.

Comment: I just want to make sure that the user name and password from my registration page and login in page match.

Comment: what is the values of left and right side of this `if(newName != TextBoxUserNameMatch.Text)` when you debug?